# How to remove myself as developer from a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I'm apparently still registered as a developer of a 3rd party Facebook app that I haven't touched in years.

I want to stop being a registered developer for this app, but I can't find a way to leave it. Tapping my name under "Roles" in the Facebook developer portal just brings me to my profile.

How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover over the name and avatar image, an "x" should appear in the upper right corner. If that is not the case, maybe you are the very last Administrator of the App?

Edit: On mobile, there does not seem to be any way to remove yourself, as the hover event is missing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. That could explain why it was not apparent on my phone.

Comment: Yes, this was a touchscreen issue. Worked fine with mouse-over. I should add that I was never an admin.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ there should be a list of applications you're part of. If you click the arrow to show the options for each of them, there's an option to "give up being a developer".